# "errorMessage": "event is not defined" in lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am creating my first Alexa skill which fetches data from dynamodb table. I am naive in node.js and alexa both. I was successfully able to create a sample Space geek skill set , and then when I created my own skill set I used the same package( to make sure the libraries, response files remain the same) but only changed the index.js ( which is my lambda funnction). When I am testing this function on lambda console , I am getting the below error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "event is not defined",
  "errorType": "ReferenceError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
  ]
}
```

This function used to work perfectly fine without using alexa. Now I am not able to debug the issue. I tested this from alexa skill testing then got the below error:

*The remote endpoint could not be called or response it returned was invalid*

My folder structure is:

-Node_Modules

-index.js

-template.yaml

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you referencing `event` somewhere in your code? Without seeing the code it looks that way. I'm assuming in Lambda you're trying to reference the `event` to get the payload from Alexa but it sounds like you're not doing that correctly.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.js`, you should have a function with `event` in argument, even if you don't use it :

`exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => { [...] };`